# Video Uploading to a specific channel on a Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, youtube-api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to figure out how to let users of my app post a video file on my site that is then posted to my site's video channel. At this point I don't care if I use you tube or vimeo. I'm struggling to figure out how to do this in either platform.

My struggle with the vimeo gem is that the documentation doesn't tell me where to put anything. I don't understand how to read the instructions beyond installing  the gem.

My problem with you tube is that all the tutorials I can find want to start from the point where you add a link to content that is already posted.

Does anyone know where to find resources for how to setup you tube or vimeo video uploading, with instructions that tell you where to put bits of code inside an app?

It's not enough for me to say:

"First, instantiate the Base class:

base = Vimeo::Advanced::Base.new("consumer_key", "consumer_secret")"

I don't now what that means. Am I supposed to make some kind of initialiser to put this line into?

Does anyone know how to upload video files, to a rails 4 app, and have the app post the video to a specific channel?

Answer (score 0):

Even if there was a way to make this work, you'd need to have a lot of trust in your users, as YouTube and Vimeo are quite strict with handling copyright and other "harmful" content (see [YouTube Guidelines](https://www.youtube.com/yt/policyandsafety/communityguidelines.html)). On YouTube your channel might even get banned by uploading three videos that "cross the line" and Vimeo says "Upload only videos you created yourself." in their [Guidelines](https://vimeo.com/help/guidelines).

Are you really willing to take the risk of having your presumably big channel banned only because one user decides to upload some copyright infringing videos?

Comment: Thanks Otto. these are valid concerns, but I'm comfortable that I have a process to handle this. I perceive that the risk would be the same to me if I were to share a video that another user had posted online elsewhere.